# NSInternalInconsistencyException PDF Viewer

Tags: pdf, viewer

I copied some good pdf viewing code from Julius Oklamcak. https://github.com/vfr/Viewer
It works great in his app when I do not modify it, but it gets messed up when I put it in my own app. 
I removed the print, bookmark, and tile view buttons fyi.

The DONE button is not working.

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
2012-12-18 10:01:45.857 TeacherTableView4[1147:907] *** Assertion failure in -[ReaderViewController tappedInToolbar:doneButton:], (...my path to)/TeacherTableView4/ReaderViewController.m:844
2012-12-18 10:01:45.859 TeacherTableView4[1147:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate must respond to -dismissReaderViewController:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x371b52a3 0x3bd9497f 0x371b515d 0x3a2682af 0x40967 0x3c9f1 0x3676f0a5 0x3676f057 0x3676f035 0x3676e8eb 0x3676ede1 0x366975f1 0x36684801 0x3668411b 0x34a4f5a3 0x34a4f1d3 0x3718a173 0x3718a117 0x37188f99 0x370fbebd 0x370fbd49 0x34a4e2eb 0x366d82f9 0x414bd 0x36557b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tappedInToolbar:(ReaderMainToolbar *)toolbar doneButton:(UIButton *)button
{
#ifdef DEBUGX
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
#endif

#if (READER_STANDALONE == FALSE) // Option

[document saveReaderDocument]; // Save any ReaderDocument object changes

[[ReaderThumbQueue sharedInstance] cancelOperationsWithGUID:document.guid];

[[ReaderThumbCache sharedInstance] removeAllObjects]; // Empty the thumb cache

//COMMENTED OUT BY ME
//if (printInteraction != nil) [printInteraction dismissAnimated:NO]; // Dismiss

if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissReaderViewController:)] == YES)
{
    [delegate dismissReaderViewController:self]; // Dismiss the ReaderViewController
}
else // We have a "Delegate must respond to -dismissReaderViewController: error"
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Delegate must respond to -dismissReaderViewController:");
}

#endif // end of READER_STANDALONE Option
}
```

I would really appreciate some help with this guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem using this PDF viewing code. I simply added this method

```
- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *) viewController 
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

to the .m file where I'm calling the `- (IBAction)didClickOpen` from.
This is mainly due to the fact that in ReaderViewController.m the delegate expects to see dismissReaderViewController declared in your implementation file. Otherwise, it will throw that error you're getting.

Note: Use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` for iOS6 or later since dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES was deprecated :-)

Comment: Yesss! Thank you so much for your help. Working great now.